# How do I get DDO to run under windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, dungeons-and-dragons-online

How do I get Dungeons and Dragons Online to run under windows 8.1?

After downloading the full installer and doing a full install and updating successfully, I keep  getting a pair of Game Error [201] each time I try to connect to a game server. This is a new Acer 8.1 system from Walmart, nothing user installed other than DDO.  I currently have UAC disabled to remove one point of failure.

I've tried various compatibility modes (Windows 7, Windows XP SP 3).

I have tried running it in Administrator mode several times (and that's how the default shortcut has been reconfigured).  One suggestion I discarded was to remove the password from the Admin account on the machine.  I suspect the Admin account is disabled, I've done nothing to nor with it on the machine.

Comment: What exactly is DDO? The acronym could be anything

Comment: @Journeyman Geek - I believe he means 'Dungeons and Dragons Online'. Have you tried running it with administrator privileges or compatibility mode fred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't answer the root problem, but I found that the [Play Instantly button and it's Happy Cloud version](http://thehappycloud.com/ddo_en_installer) would install and run when the other installer would seem to do a full install but the game installation couldn't reach the game servers on a new Windows 8.1 system.

It's possible that I had a corrupted download of the full install file, but I downloaded it and ran it and it gave no error messages.  I would hope that an online game vendor's installer would do a check sum at the very least on itself.

Answer (score 2):

Error 201 means that the game cannot access the game's files. It can occur when the permissions are set to administrator only or if a previous patch failed.

Best is to reinstall the game fresh from the interwebs. I would also advise to install it into userspace instead of global space, which can also be done by simply installing it to a different partition rather than the usual C:\Program Files.

Comment: Yeah, I know.  However, I've fiddled with it three times and done a total reinstall twice beyond that.