# How Do I Get DDO (Dungeons & Dragons Online) Operational On Windows 10 Desktop?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons-online

The Situation:

The game was downloaded and installed normally via Steam. With installation complete, I clicked the "Play" button from the Steam window. The launcher for DDO appears, then performs necessary downloads. When I click to launch the game (regardless of server), the launch window disappears and then...nothing.

Steps Toward a Solution:

- In task manager, I did not find any programs running (after clicking to launch the game) that relate to either DDO or Turbine.
- Rechecking the [minimum system requirements](https://help.standingstonegames.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002040207-What-are-the-system-requirements-for-DDO-), the computer in question is well-above spec.
- I read [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183918/how-do-i-get-ddo-to-run-under-windows-8-1) about running on Windows 8.1, but unlike the OP I receive no error messages at all.
- Per this [DDO support article](https://help.standingstonegames.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002527128-Internal-Error-on-Launcher), I checked for scheduled downtime - such was not the case.
- Per the same article, I checked the files mentioned therein - everything was correct.
- Continuing to follow suggested troubleshooting, I made sure to launch as an Administrator - still nothing.

In the next room on a different computer, without any special attention or modification, the game launches and runs without the slightest hiccup. As to finding a resolution, I am currently stumped.

Comment: Have you checked Event Viewer for any error messages related to the game?

Comment: This is a Windows firewall issue. Manually white list DDO and it should work. Also allow  TurbineLauncher.exe

Comment: Alternatively, don't run it from steam.  How did you configure the ddo launcher to start as admin?

Comment: @Marisa: I didn't think of checking the Event Viewer - I'll do that next opportunity.

@ BadSnowflake: How would I go about manually whitelisting DDO and Turbine concerning Windows firewall? Would I access that through control panel?

@ Nelson: No configuration changes - I opened the file location Steam, then tracked down the launcher .exe file, then right-clicked and started it as an administrator. Is there a different/better method that might prove more fruitful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue - What fixed it for me is the DirectX web installer from Microsoft [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=35) (automatic download)

Somewhere your DirectX has been corrupted, and this installs multiple dx9 dll files for the multiple versions of DirectX.

After installing this, I went from the same issue to being able to select DX11 as my target environment